# Can't Use Bevel on Certain Extruded Edges

Tags: bevel

I'm very new to Blender and have been learning from some excellent tutorials.
I ran into a problem trying to bevel certain edges when extrusion is involved.
The first picture shows a proper bevel on the model.
The second picture shows what happens when I try and bevel a different edge ring.
Why is this edge ring not beveling like the other edge rings?
Thank you in advance for any advice.
[[image: ][1][1]]

[image]

Comment: May be you have hidden faces inside the geometry, if you delete it, the bevel should work. Try to select all then press `W` - > remove doubles

Comment: If the above doesn't work, you could try to remove the doubles by selecting all faces in edit mode, pressing W and selecting "Remove Doubles".

Another option is to make sure the scale is correctly applied. To do this, tab back into object mode with the model selected, press Ctrl+A and select Scale.

Comment: That was exactly the problem.  Once I removed the doubles, it worked perfectly.  Thanks.